# How to show the approximation $\frac{x_{k+1} - x_k}{x_k} \approx \log x_{k+1}-\log x_k$

Tags: limits, approximation

In the book of Bouchaud and Potters 2003, *The theory of financial risk and derivatives,* at page page 90, it is stated that

$$
\frac{x_{k+1} - x_k}{x_k} \approx \log x_{k+1}-\log x_k
$$
if $x_{k+1} - x_k$ is *much smaller* than $x_k$. $\{x_k\}$ is a sequence.

However, I can’t seem to derive the approximation.
I tried taking to log-than-exponential of both sides and got
$$
\exp{\left(\log{\left(\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k} - 1\right)}\right)}
$$
and considered the limit where $\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k} \to 1$, but couldn’t really get anywhere.

---

Please note that when the fraction in LHS is converted to log, the problem becomes

$$
\log ({x - 1}) \quad as \quad x\to 1.
$$

Comment: Hint: [Taylor series expansion of $\log(1+x)$ at $x=0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+series+ln%281%2Bx%29+at+x%3D0).

Comment: @Andreas but we are looking at the limit where $x \to 1$ ...

Comment: Use $x=\frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_k}$. Then $x\rightarrow 0$. See the answer by Pietro Dona for a complete well-written explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\log x_{k+1}-\log x_k=\log(x_{k+1}/ x_k)=\log(\frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_k}+1)$ and that $\log(1+u)=u-u^2/2+u^3/3-\ldots\approx u$.

Answer (score 3):

Start from the right-hand side and rewrite it as
$$
\log x_{k+1} - \log x_k = \log \frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k} = \log \left(1+\frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_k}\right)
$$
then use the first order expansion of the logarithm $\log x+1 \approx x$ if $x\ll 1$. and obtain
$$
\log x_{k+1} - \log x_k \approx \frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_k}
$$

Comment: But the assumption the book is making is that $x\to1$, NOT $x\to 0$?

Comment: @Our  The assumption is the book is that $|x_{k+1}-x_k| \ll x_k$, i.e. that $\frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_k}\approx 0$

Comment: To put it another way, you are looking at $\log(x)$ near $x=1$, but a lot of sources instead describe the same thing as looking at $\log(1+x)$ near $x=0$.